# DELETE FROM subquery with multiple columns

Tags: sql, subquery

I need to find out how to delete records based on subquery.

I've tried a lot of things and scoured here so as to not duplicate the question, but couldn't find an answer.

Here is the subquery:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT t.id_col, t.dept_no, t.unit, t.lease_star
 FROM trans AS t FULL OUTER JOIN
 temp_lease AS l ON t.dept_no = l.dept_no AND t.unit = l.unit AND t.lease_star = l.lease_start_date 
WHERE (l.dept_no IS NULL)
ORDER BY t.dept_no, t.unit, t.lease_star
```

The subquery finds records in the trans file that do not have a matching combination of dept_no, unit, and lease_start_date (the two files have different names for the last field, as VFP truncates field names down to 10 -- and they upsized a VFP file).

Having found those records (and it does), I then want to be able to DELETE the records that don't have that triple match in the temp_lease table.

To begin with, I would want to SELECT instead of DELETE, as I always learned to only use a DELETE once you're assured of the correct code.

Can anyone help me solve this one out?  I've tried every variation nothing seems to work.

Comment: WITH list as (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT....)
DELETE FROM table WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM list)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
 DELETE FROM trans
 WHERE id_col in(
 SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT t.id_col
 FROM trans AS t FULL OUTER JOIN
 temp_lease AS l ON t.dept_no = l.dept_no AND t.unit = l.unit AND t.lease_star = l.lease_start_date 
WHERE (l.dept_no IS NULL)
ORDER BY t.dept_no, t.unit, t.lease_star) innerquery
```

If you insist on doing a SELECT FIRST, you could run the inner query first, and later do this:

```
 DELETE FROM trans 
 WHERE id_col in([ID_LIST_FROM_1st_QUERY])
```

I'd go with the first though, because after you have tested enough is fine if you delete what you don't need (and having them separated will delete anyway).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that did it perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM trans
     WHERE id_col in(
     SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT t.id_col
     FROM trans AS t FULL OUTER JOIN
     temp_lease AS l ON t.dept_no = l.dept_no AND t.unit = l.unit AND t.lease_star = l.lease_start_date 
    WHERE (l.dept_no IS NULL)
    ORDER BY t.dept_no, t.unit, t.lease_star) innerquery

--Inner query - it run faster

```
 DELETE FROM trans 
 WHERE id_col in([ID_LIST_FROM_1st_QUERY])
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I would use `not exists`.  To get the rows to delete:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM trans t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM temp_lease l 
                  WHERE t.dept_no = l.dept_no AND
                        t.unit = l.unit AND 
                        t.lease_start = l.lease_start_date 
                 );
```

Deleting the records requires just a tweak to the query:

```
DELETE t
FROM trans t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM temp_lease l 
                  WHERE t.dept_no = l.dept_no AND
                        t.unit = l.unit AND 
                        t.lease_start = l.lease_start_date 
                 );
```

A `full join` is basically never useful in a `delete`.  You need a record in the first table in order to delete it.  Hence, a `left join` is sufficient.

Also, the above does not consider two columns to match when both are `NULL`.  If that is an issue, you can tweak to the correlation clause to handle `NULL` values.